# Minimizing series of XORs

Tags: program-optimization, xor

Suppose you receive a list of $n$ instructions on $k$ boolean variables where each instruction has the form

$$x_i \leftarrow x_i \oplus x_j,$$

(where $\oplus$ is the binary XOR) can we efficiently find a minimal series of instructions (of the same form) that computes the same result, using up to $m$ initially zero extra temporaries?

Comment: Do you mean that in the end **all** values of $x_i$ must be the same as after the original set of instructions? I mean, if we want only **one** value in the end, it'll make the problem trivial (just count the parity of inputs in the final expression).

Comment: @Dmitry The set of instructions when executed can be seen as a function $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$. Can we efficiently find a smaller set of instructions, forming function $g : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ such that $\forall \mathbf{x} (f(\mathbf{x}) = g(\mathbf{x}))$? That is my question, with the addition of allowing some temporary variables for $g$ as well (which are initially zero and ignored for the output). Note that sometimes even without temporaries you can already do better.

Comment: Each instruction can be described as a linear map in $\mathbb_2{F}$, so the overall 
series of instructions is one binary matrix, with AND and XOR as multiplication and addition respectively. Is this efficient enough?

Comment: @RichieYeung And how would you then find a minimal series of instructions? The source of the instructions actually is from a boolean Gaussian elimination process, so putting that matrix together brings you back to the start.

Comment: Your type of program is known as a "linear circuit", see e.g. https://www3.nd.edu/~jhauenst/preprints/ghilRigidity.pdf. One usually allows more complicated instructions (XOR of several arguments), but the complexity measure is the total number of operands ("edges"). I expect minimizing such circuits to be hard. In your case you also have a bound on the memory; I'm not sure this has been considered in this context (but does appear in related computation models such as branching programs, as the "width" of the program).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I guess this proof also applies, for sufficiently large $m$? https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32267/smallest-circuit-size-using-xor-gates

Comment: Yes, it suffices to have $m=n^2$ or so.

Comment: @RichieYeung: AND is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sort of efficiency you are looking for, it would be good if you clarified it.

Each instruction can be described as a linear map in $\mathbb{F}_2$, so the overall
series of instructions is one linear map.

As for finding the *minimal* set of instructions, given a limited number of temporary variables, I believe this is analogous to the register allocation problem for compilers, which is NP-COMPLETE.

Comment: Minimal number of instructions, no ?